# How do I rename thunderbolt display?

Tags: thunderbolt-display

Currently, my two thunderbolt monitors are Thunderbolt (1) and Thunderbolt (2). Is there a right way to change the name?

I'd love to have a Thunderbolt (Left) and Thunderbolt (Right)

Comment: It gets the name from the EDID data from the monitor itself. You need to edit that info to change the name

Comment: And how can you change the EDID data from the monitor itself?

Comment: There is another thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350345/how-to-edit-a-monitors-edid-information-to-change-its-preferred-resolution about editing EDID informatin, just quickly reading it, I am pretty sure it is not worth the hassle.

Comment: Apple could easily enable this, but they haven't / won't.  Maybe somebody else will figure out a hack.  Starting point?  `ioreg -lw0 | grep "DisplayAttributes"`